# Xcode playground platform issue

Tags: swift-playground

Using Xcode playground I cannot choose platform (iOS or OS X)

It stay for me on OS X 
and even I change on Utilities (View>Utilities>Show File Inspector->Playground Settings->Platform) to iOS I cannot use resources and playground is not working.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are better of creating a new playground in the correct environment. I tend to have at least two playgrounds open, one for ios and one for osx.

Within Xcode 6.2 it also seems like changing the playground type as you suggest does work. At least I'm able to import relevant modules as expected in the different environments.